# Complex type in a define method for `Upload` in UI5

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap

I'm using `FileUploader` element and in backend, I redefined the `DEFINE` method.

The `value`, `Mimetype`, and `filename` fields are in a separated complex type inside the entity. I set the checkbox `media` for entity `Data = true`.

My define method:

```
SUPER->DEFINE( ).

LO_ENTITY = MODEL->GET_ENTITY_TYPE( IV_ENTITY_NAME = 'Data' ).
IF LO_ENTITY IS BOUND.
  LO_ENTITY->GET_CMPLX_TYPE_PROPERTY( 'ComplexType' )->GET_COMPLEX_TYPE( )->GET_PROPERTY( 'Mimetype' )->SET_AS_CONTENT_TYPE( ).
ENDIF.
```

But I still get the error `Invalid` or no mapping to system data types.
Is complex type and media maybe not working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about complex types but I recently solved this exact issue. Try the following code, it should work.

```
super->define().
DATA: lo_entity TYPE REF TO /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_entity_typ,
      lo_property TYPE REF TO /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_property.

lo_entity = model->get_entity_type( iv_entity_name = 'Data' ).

IF lo_entity IS BOUND.
   lo_property = lo_entity->get_property( iv_property_name = 'value' ).
   lo_property->set_as_content_type( ).
   lo_property = lo_entity->get_property( iv_property_name = 'Mimetype' ).
   lo_property->set_as_content_type( ).
   lo_property = lo_entity->get_property( iv_property_name = 'filename' ).
   lo_property->set_as_content_type( ).
ENDIF.
```